# Griffon desktop development - using/embedding jars possible?

Tags: griffon

I am trying Griffon for rapid desktop development, as it is so much quicker to write Ruby-style code than Java, and i enjoy this clean ruby architecture.
Please understand that i am just starting - maybe my question is stupid.

I wanted to ask, if/how/how simply 'native' java .jar libraries can be used (just any .jar, there are so many). My question, b/c to start with groovy, i did the groovy-koans. there, classed were either .java or .groovy, and could 'work together'. such my thought, that might be possible with .jars (that is, libraries, plugins) alike?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the instruction in http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/configuration.html#dependencyResolution to add dependency to Jar files stored in Maven repository.

You can also put the Jar files to `lib` folder in your Griffon project.